# Getting the file ID of a Created File To Delete- Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get the file ID of a created file using the google drive API so I can then use that to delete files. Here is the code:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($fileName);
$file->setDescription('Volunteer Hours');
$file->setParents(array($folderId));
$data = file_get_contents($filePath);
$createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```

Is there some kind of `.id` method where I can say:

```
$createdFileID = $createdFile.id;
```

I have looked into the google drive api but wasn't able to find any such method. The reason I want an id for an uploaded file is so I can delete files if I wanted to using that specific id
Ultimately, here is the function I'm trying to write:

```
// Deletes a specific file from a specific folder
function deleteFile($folderName, $fileID) {

}
```

This way, we are protected and delete the right file if there happens to be files with the same name in a given folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

1. You want to retrieve the file ID of the uploaded file on Google Drive using googleapis for php.
2. When the filename of `$fileName` is existing in the specific folder of `$folderName`, you want to delete the existing file.

### Answer for Question 1:

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```

#### To:

```
$createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
$createdFileID = $createdFile->getId();  // Added
```

- By this, the file ID of the uploaded file can be retrieved with `$createdFileID`.

### Answer for Question 2:

When you want to delete the file using the filename and folder name at `function deleteFile($folderName, $fileName) {}`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function deleteFile($folderName, $fileName) {
    $client = getClient();
    $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $res1 = $drive->files->listFiles(array("q" => "name='{$folderName}' and trashed=false"));
    $folderId = $res1->getFiles()[0]->getId();

    $res2 = $drive->files->listFiles(array("q" => "name='{$fileName}' and '{$folderId}' in parents and trashed=false"));
    if (count($res2->getFiles()) == 0) {
        // When the filename of $fileName is not existing,
        // do something
    } else {
        $fileId = $res2->getFiles()[0]->getId();
        $drive->files->delete($fileId);
    }
}
```

- In this case, when the filename of `$fileName` is existing in the specific folder of `$folderName`, the existing file is deleted.

### References:

- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

### Added:

When you want to delete the file using the file ID, you can use the following script.

```
function deleteFile($fileID) {
    $client = getClient();
    $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $drive->files->delete($fileID);
}
```

- In this case, `$folderName` is not required to be used. Because at Google Drive, all files has the unique file ID.

Comment: Just a quick question. The above works fine but I was wondering how the delete function would work if there were two files with the same name. Is there any way to write the delete function so that it uses the fileID to delete rather than the file name?
I made an edit to the question at the top so deleteFile() takes $fileID rather than $fileName. Thanks!

Comment: @itsMeMoriarty Thank you for your replying. About your additional question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.